# Python: for loop expression

Tags: python

In Java, I can use for like this:

```
for (index=candate*2;index<=topCandidate;index+=candidate)
```

I want to know how I can do this in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `range` function. For example:

```
>>> topCandidate = 20
>>> candidate = 3
>>> for i in range(candidate*2, topCandidate+1, candidate):
...   print i
... 
6
9
12
15
18
```

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is that you wouldn't. For loops in Python iterate over an iterable, much like Java's `for (:)` syntax. You can generate a numeric iterable with `range()` or `xrange()`, but consider using an existing iterable instead, possibly in conjunction with the functions in [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html).